# mysql two triggers one update and one to delete

Tags: mysql

I have a trigger that after my table1 is updated it creates a record in table2. Is there a way after the process is finished to delete that record from table1?

i always end up with the error

```
Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'table1' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

Which makes sense as the updating is still in progress

Thank you

Comment: No there isn't, at least not with a trigger.

Comment: Best you can do is to create a procedure to do so. So  instead of calling the update command you call this procedure.

Comment: yea ill just do that, i was just curious if it was possible with triggers